# Не обновляется контрол при вызове из делегата

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, делегаты

Объявил делегат:

```
public delegate void SampleDelegate(string msg);
```

вызываемый метод в классе формы:

```
...
var sampleNotify = new SampleDelegate(NotifyMe);
//передаю делегат
...

public void NotifyMe(string displayedString)
{
    Logger.Info("Зашли в NotifyMe с " + displayedString + "%");
    textBox1.Text = displayedString;           
    //Application.DoEvents(); - пробовал вызывать 
}
```

по логам показывает что в `NotifyMe` приходит нужная строка, но в `textBox1` ничего не появляется. `NetFramework 4.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убедитесь, что ваш делегат выполняется синхронно в UI-потоке вашей формы. В противном случае (асинхронном), доступ к контролу должен осуществляться через контекст синхронизации:

```
public void NotifyMe(string displayedString)
{
    Logger.Info("Зашли в NotifyMe с " + displayedString + "%");
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
          textBox1.Text = displayedString;  
        }));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я раньше думал что если пишет в лог в том же методе класса, то и работает синхронно.